# Can a thread be interrupted in the middle of run()'s synchronized block?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am writing a simple threading application. Thread is simply a message consumer and process it. However, if the thread somehow got interrupted and the message is not fully processed, I want to put it back to the queue and let other instances get it. So I had to code it like this:

```
    public void run()
{
    Map<String, String> data = null;
    try
    {
        while(true)
        {
            data = q.getData();
            System.out.println(this+" Processing data: "+data);
            // let others process some data :)
            synchronized(this){
                sendEmail(data);
                data = null;
            }
        }
    } 
    catch (InterruptedException e)
    {
        System.out.println(this+" thread is shuting down...");
        if(null!=data) 
            q.add(data);
    }

}
```

Thanks...

EDIT: Thanks for the responses. Everything is very clear now. I understand that even when lines of codes are in a synchronized block, if any of them can throw InterruptedException then it simply means they can be interrupted at that point. The line q.getData() enters this thread to a 'blocked' state (I am using LinkedBlockedQueue inside the q.getData()). At that point, this thread can be interrupted.

Comment: this is bad... i did a quick test and I can interrup the thread in the middle of the synchronized block... bad bad...

Comment: Why do you need `synchronized` in this case?

Comment: I want the sendMail() and setting to null be atomic.

Comment: do you want this thread(ie.sendMail) to pause till the testing thread is completed , is that what u want to acheive and you are doing so by interrupting.?

Comment: I just want to make sure that after sending mail, the data will be null so that in the interruptedException catch it will not be put back to queue. But this is quite tough to test as I cannot put sleep in between sendMail and data=null;. If I put sleep in between, well of course other threads can interrupt it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to David Harkness's answer: you also don't understand meaning of `synchronized` keyword.

Synchornized is not a kind of "atomic" or "uninterruptable" block.

Synchornized block doesn't provide any guarantees other than that other threads can't enter synchronized block on the same object (`this` in your case) at the same time (+ some memory consistency guarantees irrelevant in your case).

Therefore usage of `synchornized` in your case is pointless, since there is no need to protect `data` from concurrent access of other threads (also, you are synchronizing on `this`, I don't think other threads would synchronize on the same object).

**See also:**

- [Synchronization](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html)

Comment: Thanks for the light. I understand it now.

Comment: _Synchornized is not a kind of "atomic" or "uninterruptable" block_. I though that a thread inside a synchronized block can not be interrupted ? What is true now ?

Answer (score 5):

A thread will not catch an `InterruptedException` any time another thread calls [`interrupt()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt%28%29) on it, nor does that method magically stop whatever it's doing. Instead, the method sets a flag that the thread can read using [`interrupted()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupted%28%29). Certain other methods will check for this flag and raise `InterruptedException` if it's set. For example, `Thread.sleep()` and many I/O operations which wait for an external resource throw it.

See the [Java Thread Interrupts Tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html) for more information.

Comment: I dont get it. I have another thread (just for testing) that can interrupt this thread in the middle of sendMail() and data=null which are in a synchronized block.

Comment: @demotics - Oh I see now. You thought that `synchronized` would allow your thread to retain the full attention of the JVM without scheduling any other threads run (what you called interrupting). As axtavt pointed out, this is not what `synchronized` does nor what thread interruption means.

Comment: Thanks David. I didn't understand your point initially. But it's clear now. And your answer greatly helped me realize that my understanding of threading is too much lacking.

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring for the moment that `while(true)` puts the thread into a CPU loop...

If `sendMail` does anything that checks for thread interruption it will throw an interrupted exception.  So the answer to your question is likely to be a solid *yes*, the thread can be interrupted within the synchronized block, and you will have to catch the exception and check for that.

That said, InterruptedException is a checked exception, so short of funny buggers being done at a lower level, sendMail should indicate that it can throw InterruptedException.

Answer (score 0):

Yes

Java synchronization means no other thread can access the same lock while a thread has acquired it.

If you don't want any other thread to be able to access a message (or any other object) use `synchronized(message)` block.

Comment: The 'Yes' part is right. But the strange thing is how was my other thread able to interrup this thread while it is inside the synchronized block.

Comment: In you code you use 'synchronized(this) {}' which acquires a lock on the the thread. What you want is a lock on the message, so you need to use 'synchronized(data) {}'